# Unable to find headers in a project

Tags: c++, cmake

I have difficulties with CMakeLists file. I have done pretty much the same in my other project, so i know the paths are correct. But i tried to make it a bit more pretty so I created a new CMakeLists file.
Now my project fails to find the headers.

Anyone see what I have missed?

Here is my CMakeLists file:

````
project("Test Cell Camera")
set(VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(VERSION_MINOR 1)
set(VERSION_PATCH 0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(lib_TARGET tcc)
set(exec_TARGET tcc_exe)
set(test_TARGET tcc_test)

set(SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
set(INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set(TESTS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests")
set(LIBS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs")
set(CONFIG_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config")
set(main_SRC_FILE "${SRC_DIR}/main.cpp")


include_directories(
    ${SRC_DIR}
    ${INCLUDE_DIR}
    "C:/Program Files/Basler/pylon 5/Development/include"  # Basler
)

file(GLOB lib_INCLUDE "${INCLUDE_DIR}/*/*.h")

file(GLOB lib_SRC "${SRC_DIR}/*.cpp")

list(FILTER lib_SRC EXCLUDE REGEX ${main_SRC_FILE})
file(GLOB main_SRC ${main_SRC_FILE})
# Add all test sources
file(GLOB test_SRC "${TESTS_DIR}/*.cpp")
# Documentation doxifile path
set(lib_DOC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/")


link_directories("C:/Program Files/Basler/pylon 5/Development/lib/x64")
set(OpenCV_DIR "C:/OpenCV/3.4.7")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})


set(lib_dep_LIBS PylonC.lib ${OpenCV_LIBS})

add_library(${lib_TARGET} ${lib_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${lib_TARGET} ${lib_dep_LIBS})```
````

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Documents\Projects\CameraCopy\src\tcc.cpp).

Comment: Your CMake file appears to be missing some components. Your main.cpp is never used in a target (i.e. via `add_executable()`), and your test sources are not used. If you are getting this error from simply compiling the library `tcc`, I suggest using `target_include_directories(${lib_TARGET} ${INCLUDE_DIR} ... )` to add all of your include directories, instead of the `include_directories()` calls. If ${SRC_DIR} doesn't contain any headers, you can remove this from the include directories. You'll want to place the `target_include_directories()` call **after** your call to `add_library()`.